# Cannot invoke a Stored Proc From OSB

Tags: web-services, oracle, weblogic, osb

I am **very** new to OSB and have been tasked with providing some support with a couple of existing web services that were created in OSB.  The first is a simple SQL select against DB2 and the second executes a DB2 stored procedure.  When I run these stored procedures against my locally installed instance of Weblogic (version 10.3) I am having issues.

The web service that executes the SQL select statement works perfectly, which leads me to believe the data source on my server is set up correctly.  I cannot, however, execute the stored procedure.  The service works fine in our hosted environment so there must be something wrong with my local server configuration.  I just can't seem to figure out what it is.  The error I get when trying the execute the SP is:

BEA-380001: Invoke JCA outbound service failed with application error, exception: com.bea.wli.sb.transports.jca.JCATransportException: oracle.tip.adapter.sa.api.JCABindingException: oracle.tip.adapter.sa.impl.fw.ext.org.collaxa.thirdparty.apache.wsif.WSIFException: servicebus:/WSDL/HumanaWebService/adapter/Project1/InsertCase [ InsertCase_ptt::InsertCase(InputParameters,OutputParameters) ] - WSIF JCA Execute of operation 'InsertCase' failed due to: Stored procedure invocation error.
Error while trying to prepare and execute the CTS.INS_CTS_HUM_SUBRO API.  An error occurred while preparing and executing the CTS.INS_CTS_HUM_SUBRO API. Cause: java.lang.NullPointerException

Can anyone provide some insight as to what might be causing this?  If I need to provide more detailed information please let me know.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: The data source from your hosted environment is exactly the same as in your local environment?

Comment: Is there a stack trace with that NullPointerException?